# What time format are these numbers that I pulled off of BlockChain?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I pulled some data off of BlockChain and my GET request returns an Object with a values property which is an array of objects. Each object consists of an x and y property.

The x property should denote time, but I'm not sure what time format it is, and thus I don't know how to convert to a meaningful (human-friendly) format.

Any ideas?

Examples:

```
1442534400
1442448000
1442620800
```

Comment: they're just unix timestamps

Comment: Try this: `new Date(1442534400*1000);`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's EPOCH time : seconds till 1970-01-01 :

```
% node                                                                                                                
> new Date(1442534400*1000)
2015-09-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

or in shell :

```
% LANG=C date -d @1442534400                                                                                          
Fri Sep 18 02:00:00 CEST 2015
```